# How close http connection with cpp-netlib?

Tags: c++, cpp-netlib

When running the Cpp-netlib (version 0.11-rc1) *[edit (addition)]* [code copied](https://github.com/kaspervandenberg/https-tryout/blob/6311e1b694a4d540e8a499bf620931014eac14f5/httpClient.cxx) from *[/edit]* [HttpClient example](http://cpp-netlib.org/0.9.4/examples/http/hello_world_client.html) does not finish.

I assume it's because the connection is left open. 
1.  Is my assumption correct?
2.  Does the connection have to be closed manually?
3.  If so, how can the connection be accessed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Cpp-netlib [`http_client`](http://cpp-netlib.org/0.10.1/reference/http_client.html) appears to use an [`asio::io_service`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html) that [keeps running](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html#boost_asio.reference.io_service.stopping_the_io_service_from_running_out_of_work).

To finish a HttpClient program use [`asio::io_service::stop()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/stop.html).

To be able to access the `io_service` that `http_client` uses:

1. create an `io_service` instance;
2. supply it to `http_client` via [`http_client_options`](http://cpp-netlib.org/0.10.1/reference/http_client.html#constructors); and
3. when the program needs to finish, call `stop()` on the `io_service`-instance.

The cppnetlib example client becomes:

```
#include <boost/network/protocol/http/client.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

int main(int argc, char*[] argv)
{
    using namespace boost::network;
    using namespace boost::network::http;
    using namespace boost::asio;     // LINE ADDED

    client::request request_("http://127.0.0.1:8000/");
    request_ << header("Connection", "close");

    // ADDED / MODIFIED
    boost::shared_ptr<io_service> io_service_ = boost::make_shared<io_service>();
    client client_(client::options()
                           .io_service(io_service_));
    // END ADDED

    client::response response_ = client_.get(request_);
    std::string body_ = body(response_);

    io_service_->stop();             // LINE ADDED
}
```

*(see https://github.com/kaspervandenberg/https-tryout/blob/e8a918c5aa8efaaff3a37ac339bf68d132c6d2d6/httpClient.cxx for a full example.)*